# Freshly imported Android Studio project errors with zxing module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, zxing

I have been using zxing module as an android library for some time without problems. I have imported my Eclipse project into Android Studio (which I use for everything else!) and the zxing library is added as a module.

In one of my classes in the main module I reference the com.google.zxing.android.client.Intents class which is in the zxing module. I can write code in Android studio and these references have the correct imports selected.

When I run a gradlew clean build I am getting messages saying 'cannot find symbol class Intents'.

In settings.gradle I have includes for both my main module and the zxing module.

In the build.gradle of my main module I have 'compile project(':zxing'). These were both added during the import from Eclipse. I can also see that the zxing module is being built as part of the gradlew clean build.

I have tried deleting the zxing module and references then trying to add it manually. I have compared the way that this module is implemented to another project with a similar module that works. All looks fine.

Is anyone able to make a suggestion?

Edit:

settings.gradle file

```
include ':app'
include ':captureActivity'
```

build.gradle of main module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wigglyamps.littlegreenbutton"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':captureActivity')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Java class file in main module

```
public class test {

   public void hello () {
     String i = Intents.Scan.ACTION;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you post some parts of the gradle files and the stacktrace?

Comment: Sure you ar not just using the wrong package name? I assume it's a typo only in your question, but to be sure: It's com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.

Comment: are you using the Android gradle plugin before 1.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the zxing framework, but have you tried to use the maven artifact instead of referencing a module?

If you want to use the artifact add this to the dependencies of the project/module that uses zxing: `compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0'`

Edit: You said you imported the project from eclipse; I'm in the middle of transitioning to gradle and the import function hardly produces anything useful if the eclipse project contained references to library projects (not jar's). I rebuild my projects from scratch by creating a new app(with modules) in Android Studio and copy/paste code and resources into the new app's directories

Comment: I need to use the particular version that I have because I make changes to the source code.

Comment: I tried creating a new project and importing the zxing library as a module. I encounter the same problem referencing Intents from a test class