# Android - Gradle: error: package does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, zxing

I am trying to migrate a project that was previously developed in Eclipse over to Android Studio. The way the project was structured had caused a ton of issues when first importing. Most of those have been resolved, however there is one that persists.

The project uses zXing, which itself is a module in the project. There is no issue when referencing the module in code, autocomplete recognizes the library and features inside of it, but when Gradle tries to build I get this error:

```
error: package Intents does not exist
```

I've searched for similar scenarios but have not been able to find anything useful. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754445/freshly-imported-android-studio-project-errors-with-zxing-module) is almost exactly what I'm dealing with. Any additional suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using an Android gradle plugin version prior to 1.2.2?

Comment: Nope, I'm using 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the build.gradle for the zXing library, changing 'minifyEnabled' from true to false seems to fix the issue.